# Java EE 7 / EJB / JPA - Entity Manager not creating transaction when persisting entity

Tags: jpa, transactions, ejb, entitymanager

I have a client app:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws NamingException {
    Properties p = new Properties();
    p.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "t3://127.0.0.1:7001");
    p.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");        
    InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(p);

    ServiceEJBStatelessRemote service = (ServiceEJBStatelessRemote)ctx.lookup("ServiceEJBStatelessJNDI#com.marcos.service.remote.ServiceEJBStatelessRemote");

    User user = new User(123, "Foo BAR", "ertddeew45", "foousername");

    Long id = service.insertUser(user);     
    System.out.println("User has been created with id: "+id);
```

Whenever I try to persist this entity in the DB, I get no exception but isn't getting stored in my DB.

In my service (stateless EJB), I have two methods, one for insert and another for retrieve; the retrieving method works just fine, so then I can see that the Entity Manager attribute works, and my persistance unit as well as I can go to the DB and retrieve the value Im looking for.

But when I invoke the insertUser() method, I get no error but the entity is not saved it in the DB, it is like if there were no commit action at all.

- Im deploying my app in a Weblogic 12c server
- In order to run my client app, Im adding wlthint3client.jar into my buildpath
- In my insertUser() method I cant make any call to getTransaction() cos then I get an exeception.

Am I missing something?

This is my service class:

```
@Stateless(mappedName = "ServiceEJBStatelessJNDI", name="ServiceEJBStateless")
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
public class ServiceEJBStateless implements ServiceEJBStatelessRemote {

@PersistenceContext(unitName="Test2Jpa2")
EntityManager em;

public ServiceEJBStateless() {
}

@Override
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
public long insertUser(User user) {
    em.persist(user);
    em.merge(user);
    return user.getUserId();
}

 @Override
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
public User findUser(long id) {
    return em.find(User.class, id);
}
```

This is my persistance.xml

```
<persistence-unit name="Test2Jpa2" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>com.marcos.domain.User</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:xe"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="hibernatetest"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="pwd123"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

And this is my entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="USERS")
@NamedQuery(name="User.findAll", query="SELECT u FROM User u")
public class User implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(name="USER_ID")
private long userId;

private String fullname;

private String password;

private String username;

public User() {
}

public User(String fm, String pwd, String username) {
    this.fullname = fm;
    this.password = pwd;
    this.username = username;
}

public User(long id, String fm, String pwd, String username) {
    this.userId = id;
    this.fullname = fm;
    this.password = pwd;
    this.username = username;
}

public long getUserId() {
    return this.userId;
}

public void setUserId(long userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}

public String getFullname() {
    return this.fullname;
}

public void setFullname(String fullname) {
    this.fullname = fullname;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return this.password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return this.username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

@Override
public String toString(){
    return "Id: "+this.userId+"\n"+
            "Name: "+this.fullname+"\n"+
            "Username: "+this.username+"\n"+
            "Password: "+this.password;
}
```

Comment: you are using `EJB Container Manage Transaction`? your transaction-type is `RESOURCE_LOCAL`. try to use `transaction-type="JTA"`

Comment: More than that - the JDBC connection being used isn't a part of the Container transaction.  You need to redefine your persistence unit: http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/don_t_use_jpa_s

Comment: @CycDemo, My transaction type was RESOURCE_LOCAL, but as advised by Chris I have changed it to JTA.

Comment: Hi @Chris, I have changed my transaction-type to JTA, and also created the datasource.xml, seems ok from that side, but now Im getting the following exception:
    
  `Exception in thread "main" javax.ejb.EJBException: Problem deserializing error response; nested exception is: 
 java.io.InvalidClassException: org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 8323218586942907354, local class serialVersionUID = 3793659634176227230`

Comment: As it is shown in my User class, I have declared the SV UID, I also changed it to the numbers shown in the exception